# Unable to perform the vertical scroll up to the web element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I want to click on a web-element and perform some action. For that, the element needs to be visible. I have written the below code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//span[@title='Brand']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500);
```

Which performs the vertical scroll up to the web-element that is not visible. But the problem is, the code is scrolling beyond the element and the element is going up. I want to scroll up to the web-element.

Comment: Do you mean your element is still out of the view after scroll?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight / 2);", element);
```

The method `scrollIntoView` can scroll the element at the top or at the bottom of the view with the default being at the top:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Below are the supported options:

```
element.scrollIntoView();
element.scrollIntoView(false);
element.scrollIntoView({block: "end"});
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
```

Try without passing any argument :

```
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

So you could scroll it at the bottom instead:

```js
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", element);
```

You could also scroll it at the top and then by a 1/4th of the height of the view:

```js
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight / 4);", element);
```

Or just below a element , eg fixed header:

```js
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); window.scrollBy(0, -arguments[1].offsetHeight);", element, header);
```

Reference: [Scroll Element into View with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium)